# Model binding not working properly for Sitecore.Data.ID type while submitting through a Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, glass-mapper

I am experiencing a model binding problem, My id is of type Sitecore.Data.ID. After submitting the form, all the other fields gets bonded with correct data, however my Id gets changed to something else.

For example, in the form, the value for hidden field 'id' is `2fb3169c-8b3f-4618-ac78-6170fd0eb297`, after submitting to CartController, the value becomes `{{68CE2980-7611-422B-96E1-29C4CC0132D5}}` or `{{82F7914C-34D6-4009-B301-53C1499774A3}}` or something else.

I think its random. I am not sure where I going wrong.

I have a Model like this:

```
 [SitecoreType(AutoMap = true,Cachable = true)]
 public class Book : Item
 {
     public virtual ID Id { get; set; }

     [SitecoreField(IsRequired = true)]
     public virtual string Name { get; set; }

     [SitecoreField(IsRequired = true)]
     public virtual double Price { get; set; }

     [SitecoreField(IsRequired = true)]
     [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5)]
     public virtual string Description { get; set; }
 }
```

This is my view:

```
    @model Book
          using (Html.BeginRouteForm(Sitecore.Mvc.Configuration.MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName, FormMethod.Post)

)
        {
            @Html.Sitecore().FormHandler("Cart", "Index")


                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Id)

            <div>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => book.Name)
                @Html.EditorFor(x => book.Name, new { @class = "bold" })  

            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => book.Price)
                @Html.EditorFor(x => book.Price, new { @class = "bold" })  

            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => book.Description)
                @Html.EditorFor(x => book.Description, new { @class = "bold" })  

            </div>
             <input type="submit" />
            }
```

This is the cart controller:

```
 public class CartController : GlassController
 {
      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Index(Book book)
      {
          string id = book.Id.ToString();
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
          {
              book = SitecoreContext.GetItem<Book>(new Guid(id), false, true);
              return PartialView("~/Views/Cart/details.cshtml", book);
          }
          return Redirect("http://google.com");
      }
  }
```

Comment: @HishaamNamooya I did debugging and found after binding the book object the value in field was not correct. Guid part is the later stage.

Comment: If you rename the Id to CartId, does the issue still happen?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya no it did not work, still getting random value for Id.

Comment: Does the Id, that is first present in the hidden input, the sitecore item id?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya yes the Id is sitecore item Id.

Comment: Replace your current Id property with this one: [SitecoreId]         public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }. (The [SitecoreId] is an annotation)

Comment: If you change the type to a simple string does it pass correctly?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya thanx, it worked with. I think sitecore does not support binding out of the box. Changing Sitecore.Data.ID to Guid worked fine. You should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Id represents the item Id in the glass mapper. So, instead of using

```
public virtual ID Id { get; set; }
```

change it to this one:

```
[SitecoreId] 
public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: My Id was getting mapped just fine according to Item, using Sitecore.Data.Id, however on form submission it was giving random values. Thanks